# Using XDocument to search and extract Data

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am returning back from sql an xml string of multiple addresses, here is an example of what is returning back:

```
<Addresses>
  <Address>
    <LetterQueueOID>2</LetterQueueOID>
    <Address1>115 MORNINGVIEW TRL</Address1>
    <Address2>SCARBOROUGH, </Address2>
    <Address3>M1B5L2</Address3>
    <City>SCARBOROUGH</City>
    <PostalCode>M1B5L2</PostalCode>
  </Address>
  <Address>
    <LetterQueueOID>1</LetterQueueOID>
    <Address1>GD PO BOX 685</Address1>
    <Address2>THORNBURY, ON</Address2>
    <Address3>N0H2P0</Address3>
    <City>THORNBURY</City>
    <ProvinceOrState>ON</ProvinceOrState>
    <CountryCode>Ca</CountryCode>
    <PostalCode>N0H2P0</PostalCode>
  </Address>
</Addresses>
```

I want to use LINQ to query this xml string for specific LetterQueueOID's , i.e.
Select Address(as a string) where LetterQueueOID = 2.

All I've figured out is that i can use XDocument, but i can't figure out exactly how to get what I want:

```
XDocument addresses = XDocument.Parse((string)returnScalar);
IEnumerable<XElement> items = addresses.Root.Elements("Address").ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use XML for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try a lambda expression with the Where extension method. here i'm getting the address with id 2, just as an example

```
XDocument addresses = XDocument.Parse((string)returnScalar);
var address = addresses.Root.Elements("Address").Where(address => address.Element("LetterQueueOID").Value == "2").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can leave out using `Where()` and write just `FirstOrDefault(address => address.Element("LetterQueueOID").Value == "2")`.

Comment: Thanks worked great, the issue I was having is I saw other searching but they were using  Nodes and the value had to be inside the node, i.e. <LetterQueueOID = "1">. So now I know what is the definition difference between Node and Element

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do:

```
var matches = addresses
                 .Root
                 .Elements("Address")
                 .Where(addr => (string) addr.Element("LetterQueueOID") == "2")
```

However, that will get you all the relevant `<Address>` elements. You say you want to get the address back as a string - but in what format?

You could concatenate the strings like this:

```
var matches = addresses
                 .Root
                 .Elements("Address")
                 .Where(addr => (string) addr.Element("LetterQueueOID") == "2")
                 .Select(addr => (string) addr.Element("Address1") + " "
                                 (string) addr.Element("Address2") + " "
                                 /* etc */);
```